# No such file or directory libRNBlur.a - Bitrise

Tags: ios, react-native, fastlane, bitrise

I'm having a problem with the IOS project build in Bitrise. I am getting the following error:

clang: error: no such file or directory folder/libRNBlur.a

The same works properly on Macbook.
Library is added to Xcode.

PS: I'm using fastlane to run the app

Comment: Please edit your question to include information on how you configured the build and the full output of the outputs being run by Bitrise. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed running pod cache clean and pod install again. Thanks